# Missing conversationId for making Transactions on the new Actions SDK

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to POST a request to `https://actions.googleapis.com/v3/packages/{packageName}/skus:batchGet` as described in section 2. b. in the [non-consumable digital transactions guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/digital/dev-guide-digital-non-consumables#2b). Pasting the relevant snippet here:

```
return jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(`Auth error: ${err}`);
    }

    const packageName = 'com.example.projectname';

    request.post(`https://actions.googleapis.com/v3/packages/${packageName}/skus:batchGet`, {
      'auth': {
        'bearer': tokens.access_token,
      },
      'json': true,
      'body': {
        'conversationId': conversationId,
        'skuType': 'APP',
        // This request is filtered to only retrieve SKUs for the following product IDs
        'ids': ['nonconsumable.1']
      },
    }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(`API request error: ${err}`);
      }
      console.log(`${httpResponse.statusCode}: ${httpResponse.statusMessage}`);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
    });
  });
});
```

The request body should have a `conversationId` field. While this field exists in the [Dialogflow and legacy Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/reference/webhook/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#Conversation), it's missing from the [new Actions SDK webhook requests](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=sdk#payloads) as far as I can tell.

The new Actions SDK documentation links to that digital transactions guide so I have assumed it should be compatible, but have found no mention of required adaptations to be able to use it.

So my question is, how can that `conversationId` be fetched when making transactions from a webhook fulfilling requests from the new Actions SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet provided in the documentation is incorrect.

Please use the session ID. You can access this value via `conv.session.id`.

Comment: Tried that, but I'm getting a `400` error code with `INVALID_ARGUMENT` status and `Request contains an invalid argument.` message.